How to proof the existence of languages over {0,1}* that are neither semi-decidable nor co-semi-decidable
I am currently working on an assignment, and we have to prove the existence of languages over the alphabet {0,1} that are neither semi-decidable nor co-semi-decidable.
My intuition is that this can be demonstrated using a diagonalization argument. The idea would be to arrange all Turing machines (which would be coded over {0,1}) and all possible words into a table. By carefully constructing a language that "diagonalizes" over this enumeration, it should be possible to create a language that is not accepted by any Turing machine (semi-decidable) and whose complement is also not semi-decidable.
Is this approach consistent with the standard techniques used in computability theory? Are there any key details or common challenges in such a construction that I should consider to ensure the proof's rigor? And are there maybe bester ways to proof that?
Thank you for your input! Best regards

An usual example is the language:
$$\mathsf{ALL} = \{\langle M\rangle \mid \forall x\in \{0,1\}^*, M \text{ accepts }x\}$$
Though it can be proved formally that it is neither semi-decidable, nor co-semi-decidable (I think it is done in the HMU), the intuition behind it is the following:

it cannot be proven to be semi-decidable, because that would require to check for an infinite number of input, even if all of them halt;
it cannot be proven to be co-semi-decidable, because even if one input $x$ is not accepted by $M$, verifying it could lead to an infinite computation.


Thank you very much for your answer! This is a great example. But the thing is that I just have to proof that there are such languages. I mean an example is practically a proof in this context but still how would i proof it with diagonalization?

An example IS a proof in this context. Diagonalization could work, but it would only be a way to create an other example.

Yeah, you're right. That is good enough for my assignment. Thank you!
